# Swift class not being added in Objective-C based project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, kstokenview

I am trying to add KSTokenView in my Objective-c based project. I am supporting iOS 7 and above so can’t use Cocoapods for Swift. I am manually adding folder of KSTokenView in my project, I have following statement in my class.

## import "MyProject-Swift.h"

The file imported perfectly, but when I open that file in Xcode it doesn’t expose any class of KSTokenView.
I have cleaned the project multiple times, but no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happens to me many time. Not sure what is the issue. But I fix it like this:

Step 1: Drag all files in KSTokenView in Xcode Project Navigator. Only files not complete folder.

Step 2: Xcode will ask add Bridging header file. Click Yes.

Step 3: Clean the project

Step 4: Now #import "MyProject-Swift.h"

Step 5: Enjoy :)

You can later remove the files from Xcode and drag the complete folder. It would still work.